# AsyncHTTPTestCase Post request Passing Data

Tags: python, tornado

Trying to test a `POST` request using `AsyncHTTPTestCase` on Python 3.4, Tornado version 4.1.

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from myapp  import myclass

class TestFooHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return myclass.application

    def test_post_handler(self):
        import urllib.parse
        post_body = urllib.parse.urlencode({"key":"val"})
        response = self.fetch("/foo", method="POST", data=post_body)
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
```

The code fails with message:
`unexpected keyword argument 'data'`

Here's the complete trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 120, in __call__
    result = self.orig_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gub/App/unit_tests/test_cors.py", line 22, in test_post_handler
    response = self.fetch("/foo", method="POST", data=post_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/testing.py", line 380, in fetch
    self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url(path), self.stop, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 227, in fetch
    request = HTTPRequest(url=request, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

What is not correct with the above code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument name is `body`, not `data`. `self.fetch("/foo", method="POST", body=post_body)`